# How to rewrite an example without the use of create_function?

Tags: php, anonymous-function, create-function

When looking at PHP's [create_function](http://php.net/create_function) it says:

> If you are using PHP 5.3.0 or newer a native [anonymous function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) should be used instead.

I want to recreate same functionality of `create_function` but using an `anonymous function`.  I do not see how, or if I am approaching it correctly.

In essence, how do I change the following so that I no longer use `create_function` but still can enter free-form formula that I want to be evaluated with my own parameters?

```
$newfunc = create_function(
    '$a,$b',
    'return "ln($a) + ln($b) = " . log($a * $b);'
);
echo $newfunc(2, M_E) . "\n";
```

Example taken from PHP's `create_function` page.

**Note:**

It looks like with the above example I can pass in an *arbitrary* string, and have it be compiled for me.  Can I somehow do this without the use of `create_function`?

Comment: its just `$newfunc =  function($a, $b){ return "ln($a) + ln($b) = " . log($a * $b);}`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$newfunc = function($a, $b) {
    return "ln($a) + ln($b) = " . log($a * $b);
}

echo $newfunc(2, M_E) . "\n";
```

Comment: oh wait ... it make sense but I also see that `functionality` is different.  In the original example, `log($a * $b)` is *not* hardcoded, it can be passed as a string.  With anonymous function, that feature is lost.  You have to hardcode the `log` function.  It cannot be changed "on the fly.  I guess that's the difference

Comment: For that use case, you are right. If you want to build functions with dynamic bodies, you should stick with create_function. Anonymous functions are meant to replace the create_function in other cases, like callbacks.

Comment: Just in case someone is looking for the wordpress solution with create_function called in add_action... https://wordpress.org/support/topic/bug-php-7-create_function-is-deprecated/